# SOIL loading some images, some not

Tags: c++, visual-studio, soil

I never had problems loading images with SOIL but now it is randomly not able to read images correctly. Most are still working. I compared working images with the ones that are not able to load and their properties are absolutely identical. The error actually does not occur while reading, it occurs here:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

my method for loading textures from a file is:

```
GLint TextureFromFile(const char* path, string directory)
{
//Generate texture ID and load texture data 
string filename = string(path);
filename = directory + '/' + filename;

GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
int width, height;
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(filename.c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
// Assign texture to ID
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// Parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);

return textureID;
}
```

while debugging I noticed that while texture loading is working the *image contains a string like
[working debug_tex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzNuG.png)
if it does not work the string looks like this: 
[not working debug_tex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjYRz.png)

I hope I explained my problem good enough. Any ideas?

Comment: What file types are the images?  Please say they're not the World of Warcraft image types....

Comment: haha no, normal jpg and png